# Python preferences on eclipse

Tags: 12.04, python, eclipse

I'm using ubuntu 12.04
Ive installed eclipse and downloaded python for it
But when I go into the preferences I cannot find python

I am a complete beginner at this even with commands in ubuntu terminal  I can do very little but I'm slowly learning

Finally fixed this by uninstalling python from ecplise 
then running ecplipse via command line as root

updated eclipse

then reinstalled python

Comment: If you've solved your problem, add it as an answer :)

Comment: I dont want to sound noobish here but how do i add it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

After uninstalling PyDev from eclipse and removing its update as-well I closed eclipse
Then I run eclipse as root from the command line

```
sudo eclipse
```

I then reinstalled Pydev and all was OK

Comment: I was going to reply to your comment, but it seems you figured it out :) You can find out more about how this site works by reading the [FAQ] and [about] pages if you want.